# Do some action when some command is executed!

Tags: 12.04, command-line, gnome-terminal

I want to write a script **which can capture every command entered by the user in terminal** and then do some things depending upon the command entered:

For example:

If user enters

`$> firefox`

I would like to automatically start some services such as

`postgresql` `apache2` and `apache-tomcat`

So *I will provide command-names as test-cases and then I can do the different actions*!

How can I do it on ubuntu?

Comment: Have you thought of using an alias?

Comment: Alias is a different thing..And I can keep adding alias entry for every command!

Comment: I don't see how adding an alias for every command you want to do something with is any different (either in terms of functionality or effort) to, well, putting a script that checks for every command you want to do something with.

Answer (score 2):

For example, in the case of `firefox`, you can make a [wrapper script](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/wrapper.html) for it, called `firefox` and saved in your `~/bin` directory. The wrapper should be executable (`chmod +x ~/bin/firefox`) and can contain the following lines:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#let's start some services
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service postgresql start
sudo service apache-tomcat start

#and finally, let's start firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

---

If you want to do the same actions with more commands, then probably you need a script like (let's call it `start_cmd`):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ];then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` COMMAND"
    exit 1
fi

#let's start some services
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service postgresql start
sudo service apache-tomcat start

#and finally, let's run the command
$@
```

Don't forget to make it executable and save it in your `~/bin` directory. Usage in case of `firefox`:

```bsh
start_cmd firefox
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of exactly doing the same thing! But in this way I will have to create wrappers for every possible command..but If I can scan the input of terminal then all things would fit in just one script, isn't it?

Comment: Possibly a naive comment, but... if it tries to run `firefox` at the end, won't it loop back around and try and run the same script again? Might need to specify `/usr/bin/firefox` (I could be wrong here, though) - also, it is `chmod`, not `chmode`

Comment: @Nullpointer I just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer..can you please tell me how can I do the same thing for general commands like `ls`, `chmod` etc...

Comment: @Nullpointer I gave you the answer... Just replace `firefox` with `ls`, `chmod` or whatever you wish.

Comment: If I put his script in /bin then original `ls`, `chmod` executables will get overwritten! and How do I scan input to bash?

Comment: @Nullpointer You can't scan the input of terminal just like this. It's not so simple as you may think... So, for this you can use the second script from my answer as a helper.